# PHP: convert string to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string

```
[1: boy, 2: girl]
```

I want it convert to an array

```
1=>boy
2=>girl
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: i've try explode() but it is too complex

Comment: If you google "php string to array", you will literally find hundreds of answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use explode to do get desired output

```
$tp = '[1: boy, 2: girl]';
$tp = trim($tp,'[]');
$new = array();
foreach(explode(',',$tp) as $each_elem){
    $temp = explode(':',$each_elem);
    $new[trim($temp[0])] = $temp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$str = "[5: boy, 8: girl]";
$exps = preg_split('/\W/',$str, 0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$size = count($exps);
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
    $array[$exps[$i]] = $exps[++$i];
```

out put:

```
5=>boy
8=>girl
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex solution:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+): ([^,\]]+)/', $string, $matches);
$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```